# How to prevent an element with position absolute coming out of another element with position fixed with min-height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What it's the best way to prevent a `position: absolute` element goes out of another element with `position: fixed` that has attribute `min-height` setted with JS?

The situation it's this:

```html
<div class="a">
  Is fixed
</div>
<div class="b">
  Is fixed
  <div class="absolute">
    Absolute with long content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".b").css("top", "0px");
$(".a").css("height", "80px"); //this can change
$(".b").css("top", $(".a").css("height"));
$(".b").css("min-height", $(window).innerHeight() - parseInt($(".a").css("height")) + "px");
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
}

.b {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"></div>

<div class="b">
  <div class="absolute">
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
    ebjhrjbfjr<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how to prevent this by enlarging the height of the second div (better if possible with css)?

Comment: `max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;` for absolute ?

Comment: @Temani Afif `max-height: 100%; overflow: auto;` if u got the correct answer make a js fiddle or code snippet a and answer. TNX

Comment: Why do you think, that the absolute positioned element "goes out" of the fixed parent? If you omit the background for ``c`` you see that it's in the parent...

Comment: @biberman - "*Why do you think, that the absolute positioned element "goes out" of the fixed parent? If you omit the background for c you see that it's in the parent...*" No, it's not. It's out of parent. Tried also without bg

Comment: Then show it in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @biberman - "Then show it in a minimal reproducable example at best in a stack snippet. See how to ask." Looked so much that I don't have more eyes. It was in js fiddle, but only today I know that it's no more accepted. So, anyway you edited this answer and the code it's here. I can't see all in the parent. It's about less than half out.

Comment: I removed now the background color from the absolute positioned element. When i click on "Run code snippet" i see the text **IN** the green div. So be a bit more specific about what you mean with "less than half out"!

Comment: @biberman - Not agree with the background color remotion. It's not that the real problem. I can't see text in green div. There is nothing to be more specific. It' less than half out [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElNO.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElNO.png). The answer says "**how to prevent this by enlarging the height of the second div**"

Comment: With that attitude you won't get help - therefor i'm out. Good luck...

Comment: @biberman - "*With that attitude you won't get help - therefore I'm out. Good luck...*" What attitude? It's out of div and the answer says "how to prevent this by enlarging the height of the second div". Waiting for someone that knows how to...